# System.OutOfMemoryException when open the Excel file (800,000 rows) use spreadsheetgear

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I have used spreadsheetgear to open the excel file about 850,000 rows.
I get the error "System.OutOfMemoryException". I have tried to use the Spreadsheetgear 2023 demo to open, it's okay.
I used the following code, my Spreadsheetgear is 2012 version.

```
SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(dlg.FileName, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Anyone have any idea.

Thanks,

Duyet Le